# How to SubtractRegion in wxPython Phoenix?

Tags: wxpython

I have old wxPython 2.0 code:

```
region = wx.RegionFromPoints([(0, 0), (w, 0), (w, h), (0, h)])
box = wx.RegionFromPoints([(100, 100), (500, 100), (500, 500), (100, 500)])
region.SubtractRegion(box)
```

Now in wxPython 3.0 it looks like this:

```
region = wx.Region([(0, 0), (w, 0), (w, h), (0, h)])
box = wx.Region([(100, 100), (500, 100), (500, 500), (100, 500)])
region.SubtractRegion(box)
```

Traceback looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transparent.py", line 22, in OnPaint
    region.SubtractRegion(box)
AttributeError: 'Region' object has no attribute 'SubtractRegion'
```

Checking Phoenix docs and it does not mention anything about 'SubtractRegion' in new wxPython 3.0

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just `Subtract` now, since the rename to `SubtractRegion` is no longer needed to support the overloading.  See the docs for the overloads available for the `Subtract` method: https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.Region.html#wx.Region.Subtract

Also https://docs.wxpython.org/MigrationGuide.html#overloaded-functions